# can you do parameterize / underscore with plain ruby? (not camelize "constantize")

Tags: ruby

How can I turn this string

```
Problem updating customer by email on hubspot
```

in to

```
problem_updating_customer_by_email_on_hubspot
```

using plain old ruby?

what I tried

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> "Problem updating customer by email on hubspot".parameterize.underscore
NoMethodError: undefined method `parameterize' for "Problem updating customer by email on hubspot":String
        from (irb):1
        from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: Lowercase and replace spaces with underscores? Then doing whatever it is you want with the string.

Comment: Not recommended, but single pass: `str.gsub(/./) { |s| s==' ' ? '_' : s }`.

Comment: "can you do camelize “constantize” with plain ruby?" – This is kind of a weird question. ActiveSupport is just a Ruby library written in plain old Ruby, so if ActiveSupport can do it, then *obviously* it can be done in plain old Ruby.

Comment: by plain old ruby I meant in my company there's no rails in use, just ruby

Comment: The desired result is neither camelized nor constantized as the question title is requesting.

Comment: I just realized that

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We see no attempt to solve the problem, only a request for us to explain how it's done (a tutorial, which is off-topic) or for us to write code for you, which again is off topic.

Comment: Your "UPDATE" is appreciated but readers are still sent on a [wild-goose chase](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wild-goose-chase) until they read the last sentence of the question. Forget "UPDATE"! Just edit (i.e., re-write), starting with the title (the first word of which should begin with a capital letter). Also "in to" should be "into".

Answer (score 5):

```
'Problem updating customer by email on hubspot'.downcase.tr_s(' ', '_')
```

`downcase` and `tr` are both Ruby *built-in* methods. It should work off the Rails.

Comment: 'plain old' is an expression which loosely translates to 'just' in this context.

Comment: @Sagar, I thought it was referring to v0.95, which was released on December 21, 1995.

Comment: plain old ruby means no rails gem in use

Comment: You may consider using [`tr_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-tr_s), instead of `tr`, to remove duplicate spaces before replacing them with `_`.